# Rails route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

I created a new route and a corresponding method in a controller and view:

### routes.rb:

```
get "pictures/user/:username" => 'Pictures#user'
```

### pictures_controller.rb:

```
def user
  @pictures_user = User.where(username: params[:username]).first
  render 'user.html.erb'
end
```

### user.html.erb:

Just some simple html/erb

I get this following error. I know the user method is being entered, seems to be a problem rendering the view?

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"pictures", :action=>"user", :username=>"my_username", :page=>nil}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user.html.erb is inside the same directory of views/pictures? just do

```
render 'user'
```

should be fine i think

and I guess your Pictures downcase will be better @@

```
get "pictures/user/:username" => 'pictures#user'
```

Comment: ya, routes is case sensitive if not mistaken, accept if its help , glad to help u:)